# print document cannot print specific paper from multiple pages c#

Tags: c#

I am facing a problem to print using print document C#. When I am going to print and input 1 to 3 pages from 9 pages using printer setting and then command for print, this command cannot print 1 to 3 pages, this command print by default all documents. How can I fix this?

This is the code:

```
private void PrintPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripButton b = new ToolStripButton();
    b.Text = "print";
    ((ToolStrip)(printPreviewDialog1.Controls[1])).Items.RemoveAt(0);
    ((ToolStrip)(printPreviewDialog1.Controls[1])).Items.Insert(0, b);
    ((ToolStripButton)((ToolStrip)printPreviewDialog1.Controls[1]).Items[0]).Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
    printPreviewDialog1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

    if (printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        printPreviewDialog1.Show();        
    }
}

private void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog p1 = new PrintDialog();
    p1.AllowSelection = true;
    p1.AllowSomePages = true;

    if (p1.ShowDialog ()== DialogResult.OK)
    {
        printDocument1.Print();
    }            
}
```

Comment: Prints all documents??  Did you meant pages?  We can't see the PrintPage event handler you wrote, it isn't good enough to start and end at the selected page range.

Comment: yes I mean to say all pages. but please say me how to use the code that you  told me.